# Spring boot error ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("AAKASH"."USERS"."EMAILVERIFICATIONSTATUS")

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

This is the error I am getting:

> 2020-04-14 13:44:21 WARN o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000 2020-04-14 13:44:21 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("AAKASH"."USERS"."EMAILVERIFICATIONSTATUS")

[image]

Comment: 2020-04-14 13:44:21 WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
2020-04-14 13:44:21 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("AAKASH"."USERS"."EMAILVERIFICATIONSTATUS")

Comment: Hi! Can you share the entire exception using text only instead of using an image?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much self-explainable. You are inserting a row into table named `USERS` which belongs to user `AAKASH` and omit value for `EMAILVERIFICATIONSTATUS` column which is set to `NOT NULL`.

What to do? Provide value for that column.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow uable to post the code here

Comment: can i share with you the git link?

Comment: You can edit the original message you posted (there's the "edit" link at the bottom of the message) and post code. Basically, I've told you what's wrong. You should check what you did and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

It cause by column setting(not null).
You can do

1. set value(not null-java or your logic)
2. set default value(alter column-edit table)